# Accessing vector data from object passed as argument in function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector

This is my class:

```
 class Array
    {
    private:
        int size;
        vector<int> *data;
    public:
        ArrayCon();
        ~ArrayDes();
        void push_back(Array obj) const;
    };
```

This is my constructor:

```
Array::Array()
{
    data = new vector<int>;;
    size = 0;
}
```

This is implementation of push_back(array boj) const function

```
void Array::push_back(Array obj) const
{
    for (auto i = 0; i < obj.size; i++)
    {
        size++;
        data->push_back(obj.data[i]); // obj.data[i] is highlighted as wrong syntax
    }
}
```

I want to access to fields in vector data in obj passed as argument in array. Can you help me out, please?

Comment: Firstly, `Array` has to be autonomous in terms of managing its resources - allocated memory. Secondly, why the hell do you even have a pointer to `std::vector`?

Comment: Cheers, Gernot that what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly You can do it the following way

```
class Array
{
private:
    vector<int> data;
public:
    Array();
    ~Array();
    void push_back( const Array &obj );
};

void Array::push_back( const Array &obj )
{
    data.insert( data.end(), obj.data.begin(), obj.data.end() );
}
```

Take into account that the function `push_back` must be declared without the qualifier `const`.

And you need not to have the data member `size` because the vector has its own member function `size()`.

Also constructors and the destructor shall have the same name as the name of the class.

There is no need to explicitly define a constructor or the destructor

Nevertheless the constructor can be defined like

```
Array::Array()
{
}
```

Or you can just write in the class definition

```
class Array
{
private:
    vector<int> data;
public:
    Array() = default;
    ~Array() = default;
    void push_back( const Array &obj );
};
```